# Почему моя функция с использованием RegEx JS не всегда производит замену Y или y JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
var e = "Ea1yuc'IE$0HuOiOeEK5PN%OaAIeIu"

function vowelOne(s) {
  const result = s.replace(/./g, text => /[YEUIOAeyuioa]/g.test(text) ? 1 : 0);
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}
vowelOne(e)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-does-a-regexp-with-global-flag-give-wrong-results

Comment: не понял что сделать надо

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function vowelOne(s) {
  return s.replace(/./g, text => /[EUIOA]/i.test(text) ? 1 : 0);
}

console.log(vowelOne(e));
```

Comment: Y в английском относится к согласным!

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @StepanB Вам же дали [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1373906), зачем вы его повторили?

Comment: присмотритесь, ответ был дан не совсем точно, из массива нужно было удалить букву Y